# UITextView partially rendering a line of text

Tags: iphone, ios4

One of my testers have ran into an issue where a UITextView would not fully render a line that is only partially displayed initially. This is on iOS 4.0.1 on an iPhone 4.

In the following screenshot, the last line is Xxx TTY zzz. Only the top of the line is rendered initially, but when my tester scrolls up to see the full line, it **stays** partially rendered. If my tester does a selection via double tap, then all is fine.

http://shuningbian.net/files/so.png

If any one has encountered this issue before and solved it, I would love to hear about it.

**EDIT**

The code to create the view:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
    frame.size = self.view.frame.size;

    UITextView* tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:tv];

    tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    tv.text = [_value description];

    tv.editable = NO;
    tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;

    // default font size is too small
    tv.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];

    [tv release];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the bottom of the UITextView itself? Does this happen for all iOS 4 testers? All iPhone 4 testers?

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: it IS the bottom of the UITextView. The problem is when the user scrolls up to fully expose that line, it stays partially rendered. This happens on two iphone 4s running on iOS 4 and 4.0.2. Doesn't happen on my 3GS running 4.0.

Comment: I've found this problem exists on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could have a genuine rendering bug if the text stays only half-rendered even after it's scrolled up. You should reproduce this in as simple of a "toy" project as you can, and then file a bug with Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com/ and attach that project to your report.

Comment: Actually I have tried this, and failed to reproduce it. Through testing, these things "fix" it:

1. use a bigger font size
2. Make UITextView's frame 2px smaller than its parent, and offset its origin by (1,1). 

Not sure which of 2. is required (e.g. is changing the frame enough?), but both in combination works.

Right now 2. is in the code, and I don't like it, but I have to move on with other development priorities. I have amended my answer to provide the code in question.